# Get column header stored as a variable

Tags: r

I have a column header stored in a variable as follows:

```
a <- get("colA")# this variable changes and was obtained using regexp
```

The value of a is actually a column header called Nimu.

I also have a data frame (BigData) having Nimu as a column header along with the other columns. How can I use cbind/data.frame to select a only a few columns, including Nimu, into a new data frame.

I have tried:

```
data <- cbind(BigData$Miu,BigData$sil,BigData$a)
```

But this did not work. R did not like BigData$a. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
a <- get("colA")
b <- get("colB")
c <- get("colC")

cols = c(a, b, c)
df_subset = df[cols]
```

I do think your solution using `get` is probably sub-optimal and not needed, but without more context it is hard to say.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your suggestion. I used Column sub-setting instead and this solved the problem. cbind(BigData[,1],BigData[,2],BigData[,3])